# HTML5 Chart library that supports pinch zooming

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, charts, highcharts

I need to make a cross platform mobile web app that must display a line chart with pinch zooming. It needs to display sequences of prices where you can pinch zoom so that the axis scales.

I have googled around a bit but failed to get a clear picture of my options. So before I start testing vaious libs like highcharts, I would like to hear if anyone could recommend a charting html5 lib that supports pinch zooming of a line chart. It must work on both ios and android and be based on html5 and javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm from jqChart Company - http://www.jqchart.com/. I think our jqChart should work perfectly for you.

Comment: I think a disclaimer that you're related to it would be nice when it's not obvious

Comment: The fact that your website isn't mobile friendly doesn't inspire confidence.